# Java Maven dependency inheritance

Tags: java, maven

I created maven artifact, that have dependencyies on gson and ok3http.

The pom.file

```
 <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.test</groupId>
  <artifactId>test</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>test</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp3</groupId>
      <artifactId>okhttp</artifactId>
      <version>3.4.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.7</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

    <build>
    <finalName>testConnect</finalName>
    <plugins>

      <!-- download source code in Eclipse-->
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.9</version>
        <configuration>
          <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
          <downloadJavadocs>false</downloadJavadocs>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

      <!-- Set a compiler level -->
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

      <!-- Copy project dependency -->
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
          <id>copy-dependencies</id>
          <phase>package</phase>
          <goals>
            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
          </goals>
          <configuration>
            <!-- exclude junit, we need runtime dependency only -->
            <includeScope>runtime</includeScope>
            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/dependency-jars/</outputDirectory>
          </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Now I send it to local repository (later will send to Maven central) and I want people to be able to use my artifact in their pom files like:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>test</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

It builds ok, but when I try to use it, it throws error that it can not found gson and ok3http.

If I add also:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp3</groupId>
  <artifactId>okhttp</artifactId>
  <version>3.4.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
    <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
    <version>2.7</version>
</dependency>
```

It started to work. Is it possible that people can add dependency to my artifact only and other dependencies will add automatically or something like this?? Thanks!

Although will be very thankful if you give me the right documentations how to send my code to maven repo.

Comment: I think that the answer is hidden within innocent sentence `...but when I try to use it,...`. What do you mean as 'try to use'?

Comment: @michaldo well I create new maven project, in pom.xml add my artifact (that located at local repo) as dependency. And try to use the code from it.

Comment: Well, dependency management is core Maven feature. I can't guess why does not work for you. Maybe attach error message or start maven with `-X` switch to analyze debug output yourself